# Regex to check if text contains one of two words and preceding number

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, regex, string

Now i need help of some regex pros since i'm normally trying to avoid them if possible. I need it in a sql-server query where i don't see any other option than using regex.

This text must be a match:

```
####:;Approval:;EC 33/37:1-  goodwill validation
```

because it contains one of those sub-strings

- CASEID
- Goodwill

and before it there must be `1-`. I could use this sql query:

```
WHERE d.REMARKS LIKE '%1-%CASEID%' OR d.REMARKS LIKE '%1-%Goodwill%'
```

but the problem is that it also matches if there is another digit before the 1 which makes it a different number. So before the 1 there can be any letter but no digit.

This is what i've t[ried without success](https://regex101.com/r/dM9rB1/2):

```
.*[^0-9]1-.*(CASEID|Goodwill).*
```

The C# tag because i'm using C# [SqlFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) for the regex.

Comment: Well, I guess you can try this regex: `(?i).*\D1-.*(?:CASEID|Goodwill).*`, `\D` will make sure there is no digit before the `1`.

Comment: I think you just need to make the regex search case insensitive, not sure how to do that with sqlsrv.

Comment: Regarding the beginning of string: you can try `(?i)(?:.*\D|^)1-.*(?:CASEID|Goodwill).*`. See http://goo.gl/R3gVZn

Comment: @stribizhev: Thank you also, that works. I need some regex exercises but as it seems i could have solved it with pure sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use normal [`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

```
LIKE '%[^0-9]1-%CASEID%'
```

This has a down-side of assuming the `1` isn't the first character.

Comment: Wow, i didn't think of that, thanks, it's perfectly good. And it's much more efficient than a regex. But maybe you could also provide a regex way, otherwise it's not so helpful for future readers.

Comment: Yeah, just use mine. Great job, Kobi.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Thanks! Your regex is correct, it was just missing the `/i` flag: https://regex101.com/r/dM9rB1/3 . In C#, that's `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, or `(?i)` like  stribizhev mentioned.

Comment: @Kobi: Yes, except that it did not match in the beginning of the string. I guess that is not a problem in this case. I was just unaware of the wildcards you can use with the `LIKE` operator. Look like regex, but not quite that :(